# Problems with interactivity

Tags: d3.js, observable

I've made a Radial stacked bar chart with D3 but I have some issues with showing data on mouse hover.
I've written the code on Observable (https://observablehq.com/d/e748d76121cfba07) and the part which is referred to the interactivity is the last one (and it's commented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to completely test your code in the observable you provided according to a "circular definition error". There are several errors that I can tell you from just looking on it. I fixed them and commented in the following code sample.

```
  // create a tooltip
  Tooltip = d3.select("#div_template")
    .append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid")
    .style("border-width", "2px")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "5px")

  // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    Tooltip
      .style("opacity", 1)
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("opacity", 1)
  }) // ERROR: missing '('
  .on('mousemove', function(d) { // // ERROR: missing parameter 'd'. 
    Tooltip
      .html(d.City + "Febbraio: " + d.Febbraio + "Marzo: " + d.Marzo + "Aprile: " + d.Aprile + "Maggio: " + d.Maggio + "Giugno: " + d.Giugno + "Luglio: " + d.Luglio)
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+70) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
  })// ERROR: missing '('
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    Tooltip
      .style("opacity", 0)
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("opacity", 0.8)
  })// ERROR: missing '('
```

**Addendum**:
The problem you describe comes from "defining something by its usage".
There are several approaches to fix the new problems you mentioned in your comment. You could try to fix the new error which will probably lead to new problems and errors by splitting up the definition of the tooltip and its later usage. As the following:
(You must do that in two seperate cells)

**Cell 1**: Definition

```
// create a tooltip
 Tooltip = d3.select("#div_template")
    .append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid")
    .style("border-width", "2px")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "5px");
```

**Cell 2**: Chain the mouse events to it

```
Tooltip
  // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    Tooltip
      .style("opacity", 1)
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("opacity", 1)
  })
  .on('mousemove', function(d) {  
    Tooltip
      .html(d.City + "Febbraio: " + d.Febbraio + "Marzo: " + d.Marzo + "Aprile: " + d.Aprile + "Maggio: " + d.Maggio + "Giugno: " + d.Giugno + "Luglio: " + d.Luglio)
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+70) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    Tooltip
      .style("opacity", 0)
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("opacity", 0.8)
  })
```

**Recommended way**:
Instead of defining your own Tooltips you could use the "title" element which provides basic tooltip behavior.

In the following example I extended your first cell so that tooltips work now.

```
svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data))
    .join("g")
      .attr("fill", d => z(d.key))
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(d => d)
    .join("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
    .data(data)
    .append('title')
    .attr('class' 'custom-tooltips')
    .style("width", "200px") // apply all your custom syles like this.
      .text((d) => d.City + "Febbraio: " + d.Febbraio + "Marzo: " + d.Marzo + "Aprile: " + d.Aprile + "Maggio: " +      d.Maggio + "Giugno: " + d.Giugno + "Luglio: " + d.Luglio);
```

**EDIT**:
I was wrong. If we do it this way the best and easiest solution is to simply use the .style() method. You can find it here: [Defining CSS style for tooltip in d3.js body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978614/defining-css-style-for-tooltip-in-d3-js-body)

Comment: Thank you!!! Now I have another issue about the Tooltip and I can't find what it means: "Tooltip = RuntimeError: circular definition". Do you know how to fix it?Thank you again!!

Comment: I've published the code so I think could be possible to test it https://observablehq.com/@irenesass/untitled

Comment: Thank you again Lennart!! Now the code doesn't show errors but there are no interactivity or animations when I hover with mouse. Am I doing again something wrong? (I've uploaded the fixed code)

Comment: I would really recommend you to use the way i described at the bottom of my post. I do not believe that the behavior you wish can be achieved the way you tried with the mouse events. If you cannot do it the way i recommended for some reason, tell me and i can check the code again. The main problem of your approach is that you bind the mouse events to the tooltip and not to the path elements. So you describe what should happen when hovering a tooltip and not when hovering the specific element.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean! My problem is where to put my css. I have a stylesheet but I don't know how to link it to my code in Observable.

Comment: What i describe in the "recommended way" paragraph is more about another approach for adding tooltips to elements. I added the css class attribute as an extra to save you some time maybe. The styling through CSS is just one way to do it. You could also do it with the attribute or style from d3. If you want to use CSS for the styling you can use <style> </style> tags in observable. Further information can be found: https://observablehq.com/@jdev42092/week-1a-introduction-to-html-css-and-javascript

Comment: I (YOU) did it! It always gives me a little error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token... I don't know why) but despite this, when i hover with mouse the text is shown.

Comment: Ah i see it works now. Good job! There are two more little bugs in the styling. I will edit the answer one last time. Have fun coding.

Comment: I edited the way styling is applied to the d3 way of doing it as the CSS you defined was not applied to the tooltips. There are ways to get it working with CSS classes but than we would have to change a lot of code for that. I hope using it like this is okay for you.